# Can't compute gradient for RNN generator after sampling in custom TextGAN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having some problems getting my gradients computed in a Text GAN experiment. The setup is as follows ( Using TensorFlow Eager Execution ):

1. Text is passed to an RNN encoder.
2. RNN decoder:

   - I prime the decoder with the RNN encoder hidden state
   - I kick off the decoder with a start token and sample for max_seq_length, feeding the output at each timestep back in as input
3. I pass the decoded string to a Discriminator and perform the usual operations there.

Now - the problem is that when I'm trying to compute the gradients for the loss from the discriminator with respect to the generator part ( encoder + decoder sample ), `GradientTape` returns a list of only None values. If I however try and calculate gradients for loss with respect to the discriminator, it works. I'm also pre-training the generator ( encoder / decoder ), which works.

For reference; the Encoder / Decoder is almost a copy/paste from [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb) official TensorFlow example. The below code is run *after* the TensorFlow example, as I use the example to pre-train the encoder / decoder.

I've been playing around so much in order to get this to work that the code may be a bit "ugly", but here's the part that's not working:

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):  
    start = time.time()  
    hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()  
    total_generator_loss = 0  
    total_discriminator_loss = 0  
    for (batch, (inp, orig, targ)) in enumerate(dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:  
            enc_output, enc_hidden = encoder(inp, hidden)  
            dec_hidden = enc_hidden  
            results = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(
                [[original_sentence.word2idx['<start>']] 
                for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)], dtype=np.int64))

            #
            # I've also tried wrapping the below loop inside a tf.while_loop,
            # though I may have done it incorrectly...
            #
            for _ in range(1, max_length_orig):
                dec_input = tf.expand_dims(results[:, -1], 1)
                predictions, dec_hidden, _ = decoder(dec_input, dec_hidden, enc_output)
                results = tf.concat([results, tf.multinomial(predictions, num_samples=1)], 1)

            fake_logits = rnn_discriminator(results)
            generator_loss = losses.generator_loss_function(fake_logits)  

        generator_variables = encoder.variables + decoder.variables

        #
        # The line below is the one that's producing [None, ..., None]
        #
        generator_gradients = tape.gradient(generator_loss, generator_variables)  
        generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients, generator_variables))  

        # 
        # The part below here is working
        #
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:  
            target_logits = rnn_discriminator(targ)
            discriminator_loss = losses.discriminator_loss_function(fake_logits, target_logits)  

        discriminator_gradients = tape.gradient(discriminator_loss, rnn_discriminator.variables)  
        discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(discriminator_gradients, rnn_discriminator.variables)
        )

        total_generator_loss += generator_loss  
        total_discriminator_loss += discriminator_loss
```

**Edit**:
I realize that the tf.multinomial operation may not be differentiable, and that's why the gradient won't flow past that point. 
However, I haven't figured out how to get past this operation - ideas are greatly appreciated!